# The error I'm getting is: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, redis

I have been making a discord bot on Replit and when I run it I get this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'` This is my code:

```
 debug = False
owner = os.getenv('owner_id')

redis_server = redis.Redis(
  host=os.getenv('redis_hostname'),
  port=int(os.getenv('redis_port')), 
  password=(os.getenv('redis_password'))
)
```

I don't know how to resolve this error. Does anyone have any ideas on how to?

Comment: Environment variables are usually uppercase.

Comment: `os.getenv()` has an optional `default` argument. Use that in case the environment variable doesn't exist.

Comment: What code do I change to make it like that?

Comment: `os.getenv('redis_port', '1234')` will use `1234` as the default port.

Comment: It worked thank you! Now i just need to fix a SyntaxError and I should be good!

Comment: But also remember to use the uppercase environment variable names.